# Trouble with Spotify API hosting on Vercel

Tags: spotify, vercel, spotipy

My app currently has no problem retrieving data using Spotipy when on Local host however when I host the website using Vercel it doesn't work, authentication fails

```
def spotify_auth(request):
    sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(
        client_id=settings.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=settings.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri=settings.SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI,
        scope="user-top-read"
    )

    token_info = sp_oauth.get_cached_token()

    if not token_info:
        auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
        return redirect(auth_url)

    return redirect('top-tracks') 

def spotify_callback(request):
    
    return redirect('top-tracks')

def top_track(request):
    code = request.session.get('spotify_code')
    time_frame = request.GET.get('time_frame', 'short_term')  # Retrieve timeframe parameter from URL, Default to 'short_term'
    limit_frame = request.GET.get('limit_frame', 20)
    if code:
        request.session['spotify_code'] = code
        spotify_auth = SpotifyOAuth(
            client_id=settings.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=settings.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,
            redirect_uri=settings.SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI,
        )
        token_info = spotify_auth.get_access_token(code)
        access_token = token_info['access_token']
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=access_token)

        # Fetch data using the token and the selected time frame
        top_tracks = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=limit_frame, time_range=time_frame)

        # Track info dictionary
        track_info = []
        for track in top_tracks['items']:
            track_id = track['id']
            album = sp.track(track_id)['album']

            album_cover = album['images'][0]['url'] 
        
            artist_name = track['artists'][0]['name']    

            track_info.append({
                'track': track,
                'album_cover': album_cover,
                'artist_name' : artist_name,
            })

        timeframe = " "

        if time_frame == "short_term":
            timeframe = "1 Month"
        elif time_frame == "medium_term":
            timeframe = "6 Months"
        else:
            timeframe = "All Time"


        return render(request, "top_tracks.html", {"top_tracks": track_info, "time_frame": time_frame, "timeframe" : timeframe})
    else:
        return redirect('fail')
```

This is my view to retrieve data and the website on Vercel always returns the fail page however this does not happen on localhost. The only difference between what I've changed on the Vercel site is the redirect uri which I have allowed. Any help?

Comment: Could you provide any additional information that could help us find the issue ? Error logs for example